# I cannot install pyscreenshot VidGear

Tags: python, pip

I tried many different ways, but it didn't help me at all.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Root\Downloads\Testing\screen.py", line 5, in <module>
    stream = ScreenGear().start()
  File "C:\Users\Root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vidgear\gears\screengear.py", line 70, in __init__
    import_dependency_safe("pyscreenshot" if pysct is None else "")
  File "C:\Users\Root\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vidgear\gears\helper.py", line 193, in import_dependency_safe
    raise ImportError(msg) from None
ImportError: Failed to find required dependency 'pyscreenshot'. Install it with  `pip install pyscreenshot` command.
```

Above is the error I get when I run the screen.py file.

Then I tried using the ***pip install pyscreenshot***
command and ran the file again, but it was still the same.

```
PS C:\Users\Root\Downloads\Testing> pip install pyscreenshot
Requirement already satisfied: pyscreenshot in c:\users\root\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mss in c:\users\root\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyscreenshot) (6.1.0)        
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoint2 in c:\users\root\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyscreenshot) (0.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: EasyProcess in c:\users\root\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyscreenshot) (0.3)
```

I will show my code: (Source: [abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/screengear/usage](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/screengear/usage/#bare-minimum-usage))

```py
from vidgear.gears import ScreenGear
import cv2

# open video stream with default parameters
stream = ScreenGear().start()

prev_frame_time = 0
new_frame_time = 0

# loop over
while True:

    # read frames from stream
    frame = stream.read()

    # check for frame if Nonetype
    if frame is None:
        break

    # {do something with the frame here}
    gray = frame
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    new_frame_time = time.time()

    try:
        fps = round(1 / (new_frame_time-prev_frame_time))
    except:
        fps = 0

    prev_frame_time = new_frame_time
    fps = str(fps)
    cv2.putText(gray, fps, (1, 75), font, 3, (10, 100, 200), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", gray)

    # check for 'q' key if pressed
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# close output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# safely close video stream
stream.stop()
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks!

Comment: not an OpenCV problem. I removed the tags. approach the maintainers of both packages.

Comment: I don't know what's problem with this module but when I close my terminal after I install `pyscreenshot` package, reopen terminal, activate virtual environment and execute code again.  It's work for me.

Comment: Did you install [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)? It looks like `pyscreenshot` needs it installed according to its [documentation](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot/tree/3.0) By the way, in the same documentation, it is said that `pyscreenconnect`is now obsolete in most cases and that you should use the [ImageGrab](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html) submodule from the Pillow module instead.